# JSP String[] multivalued dialog data into javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, aem

I am reading the dialog multivalued property into a jsp string[] variable as shown below code.
`<% String[] bannerImgs = properties.get("bannerimgs", String[].class);`
Now my JavaScript variable needed these string array data to use for a random variable generation my JavaScript code snippet as below.

```
<script>
var bgimages = [
  "/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/simplebanner/lightning-gallery-17.jpg",
  "/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/simplebanner/lightning-gallery-18.jpg",
  "/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/simplebanner/lightning-gallery-19.jpg",
  "/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/simplebanner/lightning-gallery-20.jpg",
  "/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/simplebanner/lightning-gallery-16.jpg"
];

var size = bgimages.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())
document.getElementById('image').src=bgimages[x];
</script>
```

Now i want to load the JSP String[] bgimages variable dialog input data to JavaScript in optimal way. is there any possibility to achieve it.?

Comment: You should be able to loop over the array using JSTL tags and build the JavaScript array while doing so. Alternatively (and probably better) build a Json string from that array and write that into your page.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "less number of code"? Do you want to reduce the number of lines for your logic?

Comment: I meant to say if any posibility of retrieving the multi valued property directly in JavaScript or in JSTL with optimal way.